# What is difference between new in a constructor and new in a member declaration?

Tags: c#, constructor, member

What is the difference between `new` in a constructor and `new` in a member declaration?

Example

```
public class PspGame {

  private List<string>name = new List<string>();
  private List<string>_value;

  public PspGame() {
    _value = new List<string>();
  }
}
```

What is the best way to do it and are there any performance issues?

Answer (score 13):

They're pretty much equivalent (any differences in terms of performance and memory usage are negligible).  The only real difference is that when you do:

```
private List<string>name = new List<string>();
```

...the assignment always happens no matter what constructor is used to create an instance of the object.  When you do the assignment within a constructor, then it only happens when that specific constructor is used.

So if you have multiple constructors but you always want to initialize `name` exactly the same way, it is a bit shorter to use the first form than to explicitly initialize it in each constructor.

As a general rule, however, I prefer initializing fields in the constructor implementations, even if it does make the code more verbose in some cases.

Comment: As a side note, the compiler actually moves any member initialization code to all constructors.  This means there should be absolutely no performance/memory usage requirement differences from putting it in the constructor yourself, except that the instructions will be repeated for each constructor in use (this would only be significant if you have megabytes worth of initialization instructions for instance members declared this way, and multiple constructors).

Comment: This is a very good explanation, and actually answers the question ;) +1

Comment: @TimS. Do you have any evidence to back up the assertion that field initializers are moved to constructors?  It seems very unlikely to me, since [field initializers and constructors of base classes are not called in the same order](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/15/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-one.aspx).  The field initializer runs *before* the base class's field initializers, and before its constructor; the constructor runs *after* the base class constructor.

Comment: I used ILSpy to look at the constructor.  The field initializers are inserted before the `base..ctor` call in the IL.  After that is the body of the constructor (i.e. the part that you wrote).  So you are correct in all of your statements, just wrong in what you think that must imply.

Comment: I wonder if there'd be any way of convincing the C# or vb.net gods that there should be a convenient way of making constructor parameters available to field initializers (e.g. by having a syntax to declare a "pseudo-field", usable only within initializers, and requiring that all constructors of a class must either have a parameter of that name and type or chain to one that does)?  If `Size` is set via constructor parameter and will never change, saying `int MyData[Size];` or `int MyData = new int[Size];` would seem cleaner than having to create the array in the constructor.

Answer (score 4):

Having an argument in the constructor (non-default constructor), for me, allows for better testing. You can 'inject' certain data into a member field that you wouldn't necessarily be able to do without making that member public (or at least internal) or making a second call with a 'setter' property.

Because you can have multiple constructors, you could have a second one for testing, in conjunction with a default constructor, if you really wanted.

There aren't any real performance issues other than having to make a separate call to populate data later, or having less-maintainable code with multiple calls to the class (one to create the object, the second to populate the member).

**EDIT**: I realized I sorta answered the wrong question. I thought he was asking about the difference between default and non-default constructors. Now I see it was about a default constructor that initializes the member in the constructor vs. in member declaration...

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. You can't inject something if you don't offer that as a constructor, and a specific constructor for testing is code smell (it points to a class with too much direct dependencies). If you really want to decouple the class, take all parameters that might need to be changed as interfaces.

Comment: Maybe, but in the context of his question with this member variable, its certainly an option. I agree, in the case where you may have many properties, create an interface and pass that in.

Comment: I fail to see how this helps with testability. Unless you pass the dependency in the constructor so that you can substitute what's being injected in your tests, you gain nothing by creating an empty list in the constructor over the alternative.

Comment: I see where the confusion is: I didn't mean to say "Having new in the constructor". I meant passing an argument that sets the field in the constructor. Whoops. (that is, public PspGame(List<string> name)). Perhaps I just misunderstood his question...

Answer (score 2):

Initializing fields in the constructor also allows you to avoid this problem:

```
class MyClass
{
    private List<string> _list = new List<string>();
    public MyClass()
    {
        //some logic here
    }
    public MyClass(List<string> initialList) : this()
    {
        _list = initialList;
    }
}
```

With this code, if you call the second constructor, you will needlessly create a list that is almost immediately abandoned and made eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

The two are equivalent.  The compiler moves the initialization of any such members to the constructor (static constructor if the member is static).  I wouldn't say there is a general best way to do it - just be consistent where possible, and if one makes more sense in the situation, use it.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize instance members in constructor, initialize class members in declaration. AFAIK this is (only) the convention, and there's no performance penalty. IMHO this should be forced into language rule (syntax/semantic).